# Rails two polymorphic associations in one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, polymorphic-associations

I have the following models: `Game`, `HighSchoolTeam`, and `ClubTeam`. I want `Game` two have a `team_one` and a `team_two` field, with each field referring to a `HighSchoolTeam` or a `ClubTeam`.

In `HighSchoolTeam` and `ClubTeam` I have `has_many :games, as: :teamable`. In `Game` I would like to do something like the following...

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team_one, polymorphic: true, class_name: "Teamable"
  belongs_to :team_two, polymorphic: true, class_name: "Teamable"
end
```

...but the `class_name: "Teamable` part doesn't seem to work.

---

Edit:

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_12_24_011346) do
  ...
  create_table "club_teams", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "fields", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "tournament_id", null: false
    t.string "team_one_type", null: false
    t.bigint "team_one_id", null: false
    t.string "team_two_type", null: false
    t.bigint "team_two_id", null: false
    t.bigint "field_id", null: false
    t.date "date"
    t.datetime "start_time"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["field_id"], name: "index_games_on_field_id"
    t.index ["team_one_type", "team_one_id"], name: "index_games_on_team_one_type_and_team_one_id"
    t.index ["team_two_type", "team_two_id"], name: "index_games_on_team_two_type_and_team_two_id"
    t.index ["tournament_id"], name: "index_games_on_tournament_id"
  end

  create_table "high_school_teams", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "school_name"
    t.string "team_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "tournaments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "games", "fields"
  add_foreign_key "games", "tournaments"
end
```

**game.rb**

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tournament
  belongs_to :team_one, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :team_two, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :field, optional: true
end
```

**high_school_team.rb**

```
class HighSchoolTeam < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :players
  has_many :games, as: :teamable, dependent: :destroy

  def name
    self.school_name
  end
end
```

**club_team.rb**

```
class ClubTeam < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :players
  has_many :games, as: :teamable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**console output**

```
code/scout-db [master●] » rails c --sandbox
Running via Spring preloader in process 48525
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 6.0.1)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit

WARNING: This version of ruby is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software.
In future versions of macOS the ruby runtime will not be available by
default, and may require you to install an additional package.

irb(main):001:0> game = Game.new({ team_one_id: "high-school-team-2", team_one_type: "HighSchoolTeam", team_two_id: "club-team-2", team_two_type: "ClubTeam" })
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
=> #<Game id: nil, tournament_id: nil, team_one_type: "HighSchoolTeam", team_one_id: 0, team_two_type: "ClubTeam", team_two_id: 0, field_id: nil, date: nil, start_time: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> game.team_one_id
=> 0
irb(main):003:0> game.save
   (0.3ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  HighSchoolTeam Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "high_school_teams".* FROM "high_school_teams" WHERE "high_school_teams"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ClubTeam Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "club_teams".* FROM "club_teams" WHERE "club_teams"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> false
irb(main):004:0> game.errors.full_messages.inspect
=> "[\"Tournament must exist\", \"Team one must exist\", \"Team two must exist\"]"
```

`(2, Syosset, Braves, 2019-12-31 01:07:41.367913, 2019-12-31 01:07:41.367913)` exists in the `high_school_teams` table and `(2, Foobars, 2019-12-31 01:07:52.697821, 2019-12-31 01:07:52.697821)` exists in the `club_teams` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course `class_name: "Teamable"` does not work as the whole point of a polymorphic association is that the class that the class (and more importantly target table) of the association is dynamic. Its not needed either.

A polymorphic association uses a separate `association_name_type` string column which contains the class name which its associated with.

Given the following data:

```
| id | team_one_id | team_one_type # ...
----------------------------------
1    |  1          | "HighSchoolTeam"
2    |  2          | "ClubTeam"
3    |  3          | "HighSchoolTeam"
```

When you do `Game.find(1).team_one` Rails knows to use the `HighSchoolTeam` class and join the `high_school_teams` table. But it needs to pull the rows out before it can make the connection and of course your database knows nothing about the relation and won't maintain referential integrity.

So all you need is:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team_one, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :team_two, polymorphic: true
end
```

And make sure you have `team_one_type` and `team_two_type` string columns on the `games` table.

Comment: If this is actually a Single Table Inheritance setup you don't need to use a polymorphic association.

Comment: I have `team_one_type` and `team_two_type` string columns in the `games` table (along with `team_one_id` and `team_two_id`) and the `belongs_to :team_one, polymorphic: true` code doesn't work. I'll edit the question with details.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I was using eg `high-school-team-2` for `team_one_id` when it should just be `2`.

Comment: But how do you iterate over all the `games` of a team? Where does the `as: teamable` comes into play?!

Comment: @felix You have to do `Game.where('team_one_id = :id OR team_two_id  = :id AND team_one_type = :type OR team_two_type: :type', id: team.id, type: team.class.name)`. The `as:` option comes into play on the `has_many` side of  the assocation. It tells rails that the assocation is polymorphic and what *this* model is called on the other side of the assocation.

Comment: In Rails 5+ you can write that query as: `Game.where(team_one: team).or(Game.where(team_two: team))`.

Comment: But these kind of cases are kind of special since you can't just create a `has_many :games, as: :team` assocation since the inverse side can be `team_one_id` or `team_two_id`. You have to create two assocations `has_many :games_as_team_one, as: :team_one, class_name: 'Team'` and `has_many :games_as_team_one, as: :team_one, class_name: 'Team'`. I would just use a join table instead for this very reason.

Comment: Thanks @max . But basically, `Game` is nothing but a join table, isnt it?

Comment: Yes and no @Felix. It joins other records but its more of a domain object then just a join table. If you added a join table between games and teams then you can just get `player.games` or `game.players` through an indirect association and not have to deal with the headaches since you know that the assocation is linked through `team_id`, `team_type` and `game_id` on the the join table.

Answer (score 0):

A `class_name` should match the class name have in database.

Comment: Makes sense. So given that we're dealing with a polymorphic relationship here where the class could be referring to a `HighSchoolTeam` or a `ClubTeam`, what should we do?

Comment: How is this answer in any way relevant to a polymorphic assocation?